# Launchy and Office Communicator 2007

Tags: office-communicator-2007, launchy

I am looking for a way to use launchy to start an office communicator chat session.
e.g.
"alt+space" to start launchy then
"comm tab username" to start a conversation.

I cant't find any command line reference for Office Communicator 2007 that would allow me to do this.

Any other ideas?

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the "Runner" plugin.

Define your keyword, then set the program (middle column). The key is, in the arguments you want to pass:

sip:emailadress@domain.com

this will make a sip call, which if you have lync installed should be handled by the lync app.

Comment: A link to the plug-in would be good.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to using the Runner plugin you can create a .bat file for each contact
example:
"PathToExe" sip:emailadress
For MS Teams PathToExe is C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current\Teams.exe
I recommend then creating a shortcut/ .lnk file and update the icon to match the application. Add to Launchy Catalog your favorites contact folder and only scan for .lnk
Then you will have nice icons when launching from Launchy.
(Runner icon can not be specific)